# How to get session id and do login web form with session id curl?

Tags: php, curl

How to get session id  and do login web form with session id curl?

Answer (score 1):

Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, store the return value of `curl_exec()` in a variable, use string functions and/or regular expressions to extract the session id from the page.

If the session ID is just in a header (e.g. *Set-cookie*), use `curl_setopt()` to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` so headers are included in the output.

If you want to use the session id later to submit a form, set `CURLOPT_POST` to true and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to an associative array containing your POST data.

Useful php documentation links:

- http://php.net/curl_exec
- http://php.net/curl_setopt
- http://php.net/preg_match